# how to use numpy.vectorize or numpy.frompyfunc

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

[EDIT:I sort of brush this example up so I didn't clean up my code very well. My question is more on, how do I pass a subarray into a numpy.vectorize-d function, not specifically about this example.]

I can't figure out how to use numpy.vectorize or numpy.frompyfunc to vectorize commands that takes an array as an argument.

Let's think of this easy example (I understand this is a very basic example and I don't have to use numpy.vectorize at all. I am just asking for an example):

```
aa = [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]]
bb = [[100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400]]
```

And I want to vectorize a function that adds up the second element of each subarray of aa and bb. In this example I want to return an array of [202 203 206 210]

But a code like this doesnt work:

```
def vec2(bsub, asub):
    return bsub[1] + asub[1]

func2 = np.vectorize(vec2)
func2( bb, aa )
```

Similar thing with numpy.frompyfunc has no luck.

My question is, how do I past a list of subarrays into a numpy.vectorize-d function and let each subarray be the argument of the function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of your problems is that aa and bb are lists, not `numpy.array()`. You should be doing:

```
aa = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
bb = np.array([[100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400]])
```

The second thing I notice is that to get the second element of each subarray, you need `aa[:,1]`, not `aa[2]`.

Third, your `vec2` function should `return` something, not just `print`.

The final issue is that your `vec2` function should operate on integers, not arrays, and you should pass the slices to the function, not the complete arrays. The corrected version (which returns the expected output) is then:

```
import numpy as np
aa = np.array([[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
bb = np.array([[100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400], [100,200,300,400]])

def vec2(a, b):
    return a + b

func2 = np.vectorize(vec2)
print func2(bb[:,1], aa[:,1])
```

Note EDITS on OP's post which make this answer seem a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I sort of brush this example up so I didn't clean up my code very well. My question is more on, how do I pass a subarray into a numpy.vectorize-d function, not specifically about this example.

Comment: You ARE passing a subarray into the vectorized function... What operation do you have in mind that is not accomplished by above? Maybe it should go into a new, clearer question.